# Linq where in clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have hierarchy wherein a Department contains Teams and Teams contain Delegates. What I'm trying to do is get a list of Delegates that exist under a given Department. I tried doing it this way:

```
var teams = from tms in db.Teams
            where tms.DepartmentID == DepartmentID
            select tms;

var TeamDelegates = from tds in db.J_TeamDelegates
                    where tds.TeamID in teams.TeamID //error here
                    select tds;
```

But the teams collection doesn't allow you to refer to a particular property as if it were a collection.  What I'm trying to say is "Select all the Delegates with TeamIDs in the teams collection."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var TeamDelegates = from tds in db.J_TeamDelegates
                    where teams.Any(x => x.TeamID == tds.TeamID)
                    select tds;
```

Comment: Although this directly answers the question, I think it's worth noting that the way I expressed it (with two `SelectMany` calls) is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a join here.

```
var TeamDelegates = from tms in db.Teams
                    where tms.DepartmentID == DepartmentID
                    join tds in db.J_TeamDelegates on tms.TeamID equals tds.TeamID
                    select tds;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var TeamDelegates = db.Teams
                 .Where(tms => tms.DepartmentID == DepartmentID)
                 .SelectMany(tms => db.J_TeamDelegates
                                      .Where(tds => tds.TeamID == tms.TeamID))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var delegates = db.Departments
    .Where(department => department.ID == 123)
    .SelectMany(department => department.Teams)
    .SelectMany(team => team.Delegates);
```